# How to structure data reducers in Redux-toolkit with multiple apis

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm beginner developer developing an application with react using typescript and redux-toolkit (mainly with createSlice, createAsyncThunk).
I'm still confused on how to structure/manage data with multiple data apis

for example :

there are 3 endpoints from domain.

```
/products,
/photos,
/info
```

I've created each slice according to the endpoint

```
productSlice, 
PhotoSlice, 
infoSlice
```

each slice has reducer, createAsyncThunk, extraReducers,
then combined all reducers like below

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
     product: productSlice.reducer,
     photo: photoSlice.reducer,
     info: infoSlice.reducer
});
```

each slice has reducer, createAsyncThunk, extraReducers,
then combined all reducers like below
Actually I've spent a lot of time to find a right way of structuring data.
then I've come across this code that other developer did like below

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
      getProduct: getProductSlice.reducer,
      createProduct: createProductSlice.reducer,
      updateProduct: updateProductSlice.reducer,
      deleteProduct: deleteProductSlice.reducer,
      getPhotoDetails: getPhotoDetailsSlice.reducer,
      updatePhotoDetails: updatePhotoDetailsSlice.reducer,
      deletePhotoDetails:  deletePhotoDetailsSlice.reducer,
      getInfo: getInfoSlice.reducer,
      createInfo: createInfoSlice.reducer,
      updateInfo: updateInfoSlice.reducer,
      deleteInfo: deleteInfoSlice.reducer,
});
```

I'm actually not sure (neither is he )
which way is better of structuring Reducers and data?
or if you show me other way or examples of structuring reducer and data,
It would be really nice.

Answer (score 1):

Since the last version, Redux Toolkit ships with [RTK Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview), which would replace all those reducers with one auto-generated one. That might help you reduce your code quite a bit, give it a look.

Comment: thanks for the replay. I'll take a look at RTK Query

Comment: How would you achieve that @phry, having multiple createApi throughout the app (productApi, usersApi, accountApi...), and having just one in the main store, not sure I understand how that separation is achieved with the newer version of Redux Toolkit? Thanks.

Comment: @Ardian in RTK Query you call `createApi` once with multiple endpoints and then it manages all that for you. Have you tried following the [official tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)? RTK Query is in chapters 7 and 8.

Comment: Thank you @phry I'll check the documentation in more detail. I came up with this solution for the moment: 

     
const baseService = createApi({
reducerPath: 'baseService',
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: API_BASE_URL
}),
endpoints: () => ({}),
    

And then I inject endpoints into other places.

     
const useService = baseService.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    ... 
  })
})